# A vector of integers is not a subtype of arrays of numbers, why?

Tags: types, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

We have the following:

```
CL-USER> (subtypep 'integer 'number)
T
T

CL-USER> (subtypep 'double-float 'number)
T
T

CL-USER> (subtypep 'vector 'array)
T
T
```

And so this:

```
CL-USER> (subtypep '(vector integer) '(array number))
T
T
```

But I don't get this:

```
CL-USER> (subtypep '(vector double-float) '(array number))
NIL
T
```

I'm using SBCL 1.3.1.debian x86_64, in case this is implementation-dependent. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether `(array foo)` is a subtype of `(array bar)` depends on whether the implementation has a packed representation in memory for arrays of values of type `foo` and `bar`. If the implementation has a more compact representation for one of the element types (for example, to avoid a level of indirection in the memory representation) then the array types are not compatible and so `subtypep` returns false. If the implementation uses the same packed representation, or a generic representation, then `subtypep` returns true.

In particular, the behavior of the function `` (lambda (foo bar) (subtypep `(array ,foo) `(array ,bar)) `` is implementation-dependent.

For example, `(array integer)` is a subtype of `(array number)` in SBCL and CLISP but not in GCL. `(array double-float)` is a subtype of `(array number)` in CLISP but not in GCL or SBCL.

This is specified in the [Common Lisp definition](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_subtpp.htm).

Answer (score 4):

From [`SUBTYPEP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_subtpp.htm):

> Therefore,
>
> ```
>  (subtypep '(array T1) '(array T2)) =>  true
> ```
>
> if and only if
>
> ```
> (upgraded-array-element-type 'T1)  and  
> (upgraded-array-element-type 'T2)
> ```
>
> return two different type specifiers that always refer to the same sets of objects.

Here is what [`UPGRADED-ARRAY-ELEMENT-TYPE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_upgr_1.htm) returns with SBCL 1.3.7:

```
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type 'double-float)
DOUBLE-FLOAT
CL-USER> (upgraded-array-element-type 'number)
T
```

I guess that an array specialized for double-floats might not behave properly if we try to add an integer or a complex. The specification does not ask the implementation to guarantee that the subtype relationship holds in such cases.

---

This is indirectly related to [Covariance, Contravariance and Invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)):

> Mutable data types which act as both sources and sinks should be invariant. 
>   [...] a Cat[] cannot be treated as an Animal[]. It should always be possible to put a Dog into an Animal[].